# Use dynamic input_map when using import_meta_graph in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, load

So I am trying to load a pre-trained network as part of my pipeline. For that I use `tf.train.import_meta_graph`. Now, as I am using the pre-trained network in the middle of my pipeline, its input changes dynamically.

To tackle this, I tried modifying the input to the network from a placeholder to a variable using the argument `input_map`:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{}.meta'.format(check_point), input_map={'image:0':  tf.convert_to_tensor(var))
```

Now I am interested in the output of the pre-trained network which I obtain using `out = tf.get_collection('output')[0]`

If I assign a new value to 'var' the output of out should change when using sess.run:

```
assign_op1 = tf.assign(var, new_im)
with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op1]):
    out = tf.get_collection('output')[0] 

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    new_saver.restore(sess, check_point)

    out_np = sess.run(out, {
        new_im: image_data,
    })
```

The assign operator is just ignored and the out result I get when using sess.run is the same as without the assign operator. I don't understand why this is the case, my understanding is that the assign operator should run first then get_collection should get the new result accordingly. Can someone help me understand what is happening.